# Dropbox and (ufw) Firewall

Tags: firewall, dropbox

I'm confused about Dropbox and its use of ports re firewall. Looking at https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/desktop-web/configuring-firewall?_locale_specific=en
it states that may need to open ports 80 & 443. I've done that in GUFW on my Ubuntu computers but is there really a need to do that? On my non-Dropbox Raspberry Pi on which I have port 80 open (with the router port forwarding 80 to the Pi) implies that no need to do so as Dropbox works Ok on the Ubuntu computers.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I allow input from established connections by having used:
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
followed by:
sudo netfilter-persistent save

Comment: On my question, I think that my last sentence of "On my non-Dropbox Raspberry Pi on which I have port 80 open (with the router port forwarding 80 to the Pi) implies that no need to do so as Dropbox works Ok on the Ubuntu computers." is silly. Please ignore it.